# How to get Angular4 live reload working on vagrant machine?

Tags: angular, webpack, vagrant

I just started using angular2 on my vagrant machine and live reload didnt work initially, so I installed a vagrant plugin "vagrant-fsnotify" which seems to fix the file change detection by compiler but not the browser reload.

using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

Node : 6.11.4,
Angular cli : 1.4.5,
Vagrant box : Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by setting port forward

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4200, host: 4200
```

You will also need to install vagrant plugin vagrant-fsnotify. One way is to add this at the top of your vagrant file

```
required_plugins = %w( vagrant-fsnotify )
required_plugins.each do |plugin|
   system "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}" unless Vagrant.has_plugin? plugin
end
```

Run ng serve like this:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Its is not working for me, it does not detects file change

Comment: @CamilleTolsa you can try restarting the vagrant after adding the configuration or else try a different file notification plugin https://github.com/mhallin/vagrant-notify-forwarder. My colleague had an issue with vagrant-fsnotify on his machine but vagrant-notify-forwarder worked for him.

Comment: This worked for me after following the usage instructions at https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify#usage.